# 16.04 uses Intel HD Graphics instead of Radeon

Tags: graphics, 16.04, radeon, intel

I installed ubuntu 16.04 to my Dell inspiron 5559 that has AMD Radeon R5 M335 graphics cards.

When I run:

```
sudo lshw -c video
```

I get:

```
*-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: HD Graphics 520
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 07
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915_bpo latency=0
       resources: irq:277 memory:d1000000-d1ffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
  *-display
       description: Display controller
       product: Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M / R5 M330]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 81
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:278 memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d003ffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:d0040000-d005ffff
```

When I run:

```
lspci -nn | grep VGA
```

I get:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 520 [8086:1916] (rev 07)
```

Edit: My problem is that it uses as graphics card the intel and not the dedicated radeon.
Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks a lot in advance!!!

Comment: What is you problem exactly?

Comment: My problem is that it uses as graphics card the intel and not the dedicated radeon

Comment: There is no such indication in what you posted do far... How can you see that?

Comment: @dadexix86x                                                                                                                       randr --listproviders
Providers: number : 3
Provider 0: id: 0x66 cap: 0x9, Source Output, Sink Offload crtcs: 4 outputs: 3 associated providers: 2 name:Intel
Provider 1: id: 0x3f cap: 0x6, Sink Output, Source Offload crtcs: 0 outputs: 0 associated providers: 2 name:HAINAN @ pci:0000:01:00.0
Provider 2: id: 0x3f cap: 0x6, Sink Output, Source Offload crtcs: 0 outputs: 0 associated providers: 2 name:HAINAN @ pci:0000:01:00.0

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't support the [AMD Catalyst(fglrx)](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/03/ubuntu-drops-amd-catalyst-fglrx-driver-16-04) drivers anymore. As such, the system will try its best to use other drivers(like the Intel) to make it work. If you are okay with just browsing the Internet, typing and listening to music, that's okay. If you want to play games, unfortunately you won't be, since the drivers provided are just enough for lightweight stuff.

Canonical say: “[AMD won’t support fglrx on 16.04, period](https://lists.ubuntu.com/archives/ubuntu-devel-discuss/2016-March/016315.html)”. So I guess Intel drivers will be the best option for your Raedon, until someone does something.

Comment: By default Ubuntu uses open AMD drivers (instead of the proprietary `fglrx`) on AMD hardware. The Intel hardware uses the open Intel drivers. Obviously, it does not make sense to use Intel drivers for AMD hardware...