# What does "Supported, but hardware is too old for Unity" mean with respects to AMD Graphics

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics

I have recently migrated from 15.04 to 16.04 (A minor disaster related to 15.10 in between). Today I decided to see if I could get my graphics card working. It is a Radeon 8500 2GB, and is on the list of cards "Supported, but hardware is too old for Unity" [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver#Supported.2C_but_hardware_is_too_old_for_Unity). The message here was rather cryptic, saying the CPU  will use for basic drawing. My interpretation of this was that the CPU would be used for drawing my browser and other simple task, but games would use the GPU.

However, the litmus test I use for graphics, the debug screen in Minecraft, reported Intel, my CPU.

As recommended on the aforementioned page, I ran

```
lspci -nn | grep VGA
```

and got

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller [8086:0a16] (rev 0b)
```

However, with just lspci, the controller shows up as a Display controller

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
03:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun LE [Radeon HD 8550M / R5 M230] (rev ff)
```

I check the logs with

```
dmesg | egrep 'drm|radeon'
```

and receive

```
[    1.068355] [drm] Initialized drm 1.1.0 20060810
[    1.095305] [drm] radeon kernel modesetting enabled.
[    1.099856] radeon 0000:03:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
[    1.100012] [drm] initializing kernel modesetting (HAINAN 0x1002:0x666F 0x17AA:0x380C).
[    1.100024] [drm] register mmio base: 0xD0400000
[    1.100024] [drm] register mmio size: 262144
[    1.109636] [drm] GPU not posted. posting now...
[    1.112925] radeon 0000:03:00.0: VRAM: 2048M 0x0000000000000000 - 0x000000007FFFFFFF (2048M used)
[    1.112927] radeon 0000:03:00.0: GTT: 2048M 0x0000000080000000 - 0x00000000FFFFFFFF
[    1.112929] [drm] Detected VRAM RAM=2048M, BAR=256M
[    1.112929] [drm] RAM width 64bits DDR
[    1.113014] [drm] radeon: 2048M of VRAM memory ready
[    1.113015] [drm] radeon: 2048M of GTT memory ready.
[    1.113025] [drm] Loading hainan Microcode
[    1.113101] [drm] Internal thermal controller with fan control
[    1.113146] [drm] probing gen 2 caps for device 8086:9c18 = 5323c42/0
[    1.119913] [drm] radeon: dpm initialized
[    1.119917] [drm] GART: num cpu pages 524288, num gpu pages 524288
[    1.121089] [drm] probing gen 2 caps for device 8086:9c18 = 5323c42/0
[    1.121093] [drm] PCIE gen 2 link speeds already enabled
[    1.124048] [drm] PCIE GART of 2048M enabled (table at 0x0000000000040000).
[    1.124150] radeon 0000:03:00.0: WB enabled
[    1.124152] radeon 0000:03:00.0: fence driver on ring 0 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c00 and cpu addr 0xffff88023f95cc00
[    1.124153] radeon 0000:03:00.0: fence driver on ring 1 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c04 and cpu addr 0xffff88023f95cc04
[    1.124154] radeon 0000:03:00.0: fence driver on ring 2 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c08 and cpu addr 0xffff88023f95cc08
[    1.124155] radeon 0000:03:00.0: fence driver on ring 3 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c0c and cpu addr 0xffff88023f95cc0c
[    1.124157] radeon 0000:03:00.0: fence driver on ring 4 use gpu addr 0x0000000080000c10 and cpu addr 0xffff88023f95cc10
[    1.124158] radeon 0000:03:00.0: VCE init error (-22).
[    1.124159] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[    1.124160] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[    1.124161] radeon 0000:03:00.0: radeon: MSI limited to 32-bit
[    1.124185] radeon 0000:03:00.0: radeon: using MSI.
[    1.124209] [drm] radeon: irq initialized.
[    1.317816] [drm] ring test on 0 succeeded in 1 usecs
[    1.317821] [drm] ring test on 1 succeeded in 1 usecs
[    1.317825] [drm] ring test on 2 succeeded in 1 usecs
[    1.317833] [drm] ring test on 3 succeeded in 4 usecs
[    1.317839] [drm] ring test on 4 succeeded in 4 usecs
[    1.318022] [drm] ib test on ring 0 succeeded in 0 usecs
[    1.318047] [drm] ib test on ring 1 succeeded in 0 usecs
[    1.318070] [drm] ib test on ring 2 succeeded in 0 usecs
[    1.318088] [drm] ib test on ring 3 succeeded in 0 usecs
[    1.318108] [drm] ib test on ring 4 succeeded in 0 usecs
[    1.318816] [drm] Radeon Display Connectors
[    1.320981] [drm] Initialized radeon 2.43.0 20080528 for 0000:03:00.0 on minor 0
[    1.321444] [drm] Memory usable by graphics device = 2048M
[    1.321448] fb: switching to inteldrmfb from EFI VGA
[    1.322193] [drm] Replacing VGA console driver
[    1.328455] [drm] Supports vblank timestamp caching Rev 2 (21.10.2013).
[    1.328458] [drm] Driver supports precise vblank timestamp query.
[    1.349260] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20151010 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 1
[    1.496740] fbcon: inteldrmfb (fb0) is primary device
[    1.496851] i915 0000:00:02.0: fb0: inteldrmfb frame buffer device
```

Everything seems to be going right other than:

```
VCE init error (-22).
```

and possibly

```
switching to inteldrmfb from EFI VGA
```

Was my original interpretation wrong and I can't use my GPU at all with 16.04? Do I need to do something to switch it on? The page suggest I try a lighter desktop. Would that make my card work, or simply compensate with less load on the CPU? What is the difference between a VGA compatible controller and a Display controller?

EDIT: Tried what ILOVEKODI suggusted, which helped some, and updated logs accordingly.

EDIT2: Tried as eyoung100, and saw that it sees my card, but didn't mark it as a VGA compatible controller.

Comment: Please add the output of `lspci` as a whole.

Comment: @eyoung100 Thank you for the suggestion, it seems to have provided a clue.

Comment: The message there is pretty clear:  "These cards will not run Ubuntu's Unity desktop with 3D acceleration. They will still run Unity, but the CPU will be used for basic drawing and performance may suffer. If you have one of these cards, a lighter desktop (such as XFCE or LXDE, found in Xubuntu and Lubuntu respectively) is recommended. " Please try xubuntu or lubuntu.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has no solution that isn't already given in the message quoted by the OP.

Comment: @chaskes Do you know if those are recommend because they are lighter on the CPU or because my GPU can be used for 3D applications on those desktops? That is my confusion.

Comment: Your gpu will not be used for 3d acceleration on Unity. Period. xfce and lxde do not require 3d acceleration to work. Will they correctly use the gpu for 3d accel in the lighter environment? I don't know for sure, but I think yes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The driver is attempting to initialize VCE on a card that does not support it. The message is totally harmless - just ignore it.

```
sudo apt purge libgtk2.0-0:amd64

sudo apt install libgtk2.0-0:amd64
```

The above command should solve the issue with the VCE issue.

AMD catalyst is no longer supported as of 16.04

Comment: Thank you, that made one of the VCE errors go away. Unfortunately there seems to be more to the issue, as it still switches to Intel graphics. Warning for Googlers this uninstalls chrome and firefox.

Comment: Should be able to reinstall my bad on that one. I'll see what else I can find on the Intel amd issue

Comment: Bad news, amd won't support graphics starting 16.04. http://askubuntu.com/questions/769053/16-04-uses-intel-hd-graphics-instead-of-radeon

Comment: Also if I helped, please mark my answer as the answer, thanks

Comment: The propriety amd drivers are not supported in 16.04, but according to  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RadeonDriver the open source drivers are in a good state, and my card is "Supported, but hardware is too old for Unity". I normally don't mark partial or "it can't be done" answers until it is clear that a better one isn't coming.